# Find the determinant of a matrix $A$, such that $A^4 + 2A = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Find the determinant of an revertible, $6 \times 6$ matrix $A$, such that $A^4 + 2A = 0$

---

This question seems odd to me, because when I tried to solve it:

$A^4 + 2A = O$

$(A^3+2I)A = O\det$

$|(A^3+2I)||A| = |O|$

But I **know** that $|A|$ is revertible, thus $|A| != 0$, which must mean that $|(A^3+2I)| = 0$.

But if I try:

$|(A^3+2I)||A| = |O|$

$0|A| = 0$
which means it true for every $6 * 6$ matrices, but the question specified $1$.

What am I getting wrong here, and how should I solve this?

**edit:**

Here is another thing I have tried:

$A^4+2A=0$

$(A^3+2I)A = 0$

$A^3+2I=0$

$A^3=-2I$

$A^3=-2A*A^-1$

$A^2=-2*A^-1\det$

$|A^2|/2=-2*(1/|A|)$

$|A| * |A| / 1 = -2/|A|$

$|A|^3 = -2 $

$|A|=-1.2599$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A^4+2A = 0 \implies A^4 = -2A \implies \det(A^4) = \det(-2A^4) \implies \det(A)^4 = (-2)^6\det(A)$. Let $\det(A) = x$, then the last equation reduces to $x^4 = (-2)^6x$. So $$x(x^3+2^6) = 0$$

Since $A$ is invertible, the only possibility is $x = -2^2$.

Comment: -3A? shouldent it be -2A?

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: I think that $\det A$ should be equal to $4$. This step $x^4 = (-2)^6x \implies x(x^3+2^6) = 0$ seems uncorrect.

Answer (score 5):

We have that

$$A^4+2A=0\implies A^{-1}A^4+2A^{-1}A=0\implies A^3=-2I $$

$$\implies \det (A^3) = \det (-2I)=2^6$$

then by $\det(XY)=\det X \:\det Y$ we have

$$\det (A^3)=(\det A)^3=2^6 \implies \det A=2^2=4$$

Comment: why det(-2I) = 2^6???

Comment: For a $n \times n$ -matrix $A$ and a scalar $t$ we have: $ \det(tA)=t^n \det(A).$

Comment: $-2I $ is a diagonal matrix and the determinant in this case is the product of diagonal entries.